# How to remove a layer on map using checkbox in openlayers 5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers-5

I want help in removing layer on map using openlayers 5 . I have done to add the the layer on map using checkbox .
what i want is that if the checkbox of that is layer is checked the layer will appear on map , and if the checkbox is unchecked again the layer will br removed from the map.
I have tried the following code the code adds the layer on map but not removing it.

```
     var checkbase = $('#main-side input')
  $(checkbase).change(function(){
   let checked = $(this)

   let checkedVal = $(this).val();
    test = new ol.layer.Image({
      source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: "http://3.16.123.168:8080/geoserver/wms?",
        params: {
          LAYERS: `twmp:${checkedVal} `
        },
        ratio: 1,
        serverType: "geoserver",
        crossOrigin: "anonymous"
      })
    });

    if (checked.is(':checked')) {
        map.addLayer(test);
    } else {
         map.removeLayer(test);

    }

  })
```

I have tried several methods for this like map.removeLayer and map.dispose and if the checkbox is unchecked remove the layer but  not working.

Comment: You are redefining `test` every time the checkbox changes so `removeLayer` will try to remove a newly created layer which has not been added instead of the old one

Comment: I dont understand what are you saying.

Answer (score 0):

You should not set `test` to a new layer before you remove the old value.  You code should look something like this

```
  var test;
  var checkbase = $('#main-side input')
  $(checkbase).change(function(){
   let checked = $(this)

   let checkedVal = $(this).val();

    if (checked.is(':checked')) {
        test = new ol.layer.Image({
          source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: "http://3.16.123.168:8080/geoserver/wms?",
            params: {
              LAYERS: `twmp:${checkedVal} `
            },
            ratio: 1,
            serverType: "geoserver",
            crossOrigin: "anonymous"
          })
        });
        map.addLayer(test);
    } else {
         map.removeLayer(test);

    }

  })
```

Comment: This is exactly i have been running the the test variable is my global variable. but it is not working.